# Slider Element Hides on Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have small problem but i unable to resolve it that my slider shows on desktop fine . whenever i run website on mobile image hide 20% from left side . please check and reply .thank you .[website here](https://www.toysandsport.com)

Comment: You need to supply a [reprex], SO is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MediaQuery of css :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
  #your-element {
    display:none;
  }

}

#your-element{
display: block;
}
```

For more detail please go to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: it is not element it image hide 20% from left

Comment: thank you i change background-size:90% top  to background-size:0% top; run fine. please make my question point thanks

Comment: Thanks your question is very "blur" please ask clearly in the future :D  Happy coding